# Where does linux look for shared libs?

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to get the ar command on an embedded ARM computer running linux. I want to install debian and openjdk. It is a headless system. This is a custom linux distribution provided by the hardware manufacturer.

The debian installer is missing the ar command so i tried copying the binaries from the debian package, but when running ar I get  error while loading shared libraries: libbfd-2.18.0-multiarch.20080103.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

libbfd is also in the package. I tried linking it to /lib and /usr/lib but I get the same message when running.

What is the best way to get debian and ar on a custom linux distro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loader uses the hints provided by `ldconfig` to look for shared libraries, as well as a couple of well-known places (`/lib` and `/usr/lib`, modified appropriately for the platform).

Comment: ok. Only problem is ldconfig is not available on my box

Comment: I found the problem. The symlink was broken and I didn't notice because the shell highlighted it in a color indicating a good link.

Comment: You can also check out the /etc/ld.so.conf file (used by ldconfig) and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.